# Arch Linux Zen : How to fix virtualbox vboxdrv module

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel

I am running Arch linux with Zen kernel.

`Linux Glory 4.15.4-1-zen #1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT Sat Feb 17 16:01:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I installed virtualbox via the official wiki and done everything right. 
I still get this error when running the vboxmanage --version:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.15.4-1-zen) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.2.6r120293
```

anything i can try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by installing the `linux-zen-headers`. which were not present.

Answer (score 0):

Either sign the Virtalbox (`vboxdrv`)driver or disable Secure Boot in the firmware (UEFI) settings.